# Launch jar file and display in console

Tags: java, jruby

I recently made a jar file using JRuby and Rawr.  The program just writes the word 'hello' to STDOUT and then waits for the user to hit enter.

To run the program, I have to type `java -jar MyProgram.jar`.  I'd like to know if it is possible to make it so that when the user double click on the *.jar file, the console automatically pops up displaying 'hello' (rather than having to execute `java -jar MyProgram.jar` every time I want to run the program).  I guess I could create a batch file, but is there a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Some Java .exe wrappers, like JSmooth allows you to wrap your jar in an exe file, and pop the console.